# NativeScript RadListView Scroll to bottom issue

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am using RadListView and I am trying to scroll to the bottom of the list. It works great on Android and iOS until I add a header to the RadList. Once I add a header on Android it will scroll to the second to the last item, not all the way down.

[See playground example here.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mbMo8E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mbMo8E&v=2).
If you change it to

```
this.radList.scrollToIndex(this._dataItems.length - 1, false, ListViewItemSnapMode.Auto);
```

or

```
this.radList.scrollToIndex(this._dataItems.length - 1, false);
```

It works fine on both android and ios. [ListViewItemSnapMode.Auto](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/enums/listviewitemsnapmode) : The target item is snapped at the closest possible position which makes it clearly visible.